# How can I check files In using OData for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, rest, check-in, odata

I am uploading files to SharePoint 2010 following the answer here: [Uploading files to Document Libraries using the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26553/uploading-files-to-document-libraries-using-the-rest-api)

The issue is that all of the files are set as checked out due to some required fields in the list. I an using the OData API to update the column values, but I want to automatically check in the files. Is this even possible?

Here's how I'm updating the entities.

```
    Planning.PlanningDataContext context = new Planning.PlanningDataContext(new System.Uri("http://sharepoint/Service/ds/plan/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
    context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    for (int i=0; i < Studies.Count; i++)
    {
        var study = Studies[i];
        PutFileOnSP(study);
        var serverStudy = context.GeotechnicalStudies.Where(s => s.Name == study.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        serverStudy.StudyArea = study.StudyArea;
        serverStudy.StudyPerformedBy = study.StudyPerformedBy;
        serverStudy.StudyNumber = study.StudyNumber;
        context.UpdateObject(serverStudy);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible using the `ListData.svc`. But you can do it using the Managed Client Side Object Model. I'm not on my dev system right now but I will add a code sample tomorrow.

**Edit:**

Just to be certain I attempted to check in a document in my dev server's Shared Documents library using `ListData.svc`. I attempted to do it by sending a `DELETE` request to

`../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SharedDocuments(1)/$links/CheckedOutTo`

I did not receive any error but no modification was made. I also sent a `POST` request trying to set the `CheckedOutToId` to `null`. This didn't work either. So I honestly belive there is no way of doing this via the SP 2010 REST API. Here is example code using the Managed Client Object model. This was tested in a console app on my work laptop to my development server.

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://devserver.domain.com/");
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        List sharedDocs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
        clientContext.Load(sharedDocs);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        ListItem item = sharedDocs.GetItemById(1);
        File file = item.File;
        file.CheckIn("Checkin comments.", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
        clientContext.Load(file);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with the SOAP interface of ShPt2010. (More recent versions have a slightly different interface, but still in SOAP.) The documentation is contained in any standard ShPt site (probably also yours), for example at 
https://www.h10hotels.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?op=CheckInFile

Assuming your checked out file is `https://example.net/subsite/Pages/file.aspx`, then you can use an HTTP POST request with parameters

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile
```

and content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <CheckInFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <pageUrl>https://example.net/subsite/Pages/file.aspx</pageUrl>
            <comment>Describe what you did here.</comment>
            <checkinType>0</checkinType>
        </CheckInFile>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For example using a shell script and `curl` under Linux, you can implement this as follows:

```
cat <<EoSOAP |
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <CheckInFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <pageUrl>https://example.net/subsite/Pages/file.aspx</pageUrl>
            <comment>Describe what you did here.</comment>
            <checkinType>0</checkinType>
        </CheckInFile>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EoSOAP
curl -d @- \
-H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
-H 'SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile"' \
https://example.net/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx |
sed 's/.*<soap:Body>/\t/; s@</soap:Body>.*@\n@;'
```

(where the last line is just cosmetics to strip of the frame from the response to make it a bit nicer).