# Read, Write, CheckIn/Out files in SharePoint 2010 with REST

Tags: 2010, rest, file

Is there a way to Read, Write, CheckIn/Out files in SharePoint 2010 with REST?
It is possible with SOAP but transferring base64-encoded seems to be inefficient.
Thanks

Comment: I gave an answer for CheckIn in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52529/how-can-i-check-files-in-using-odata-for-sharepoint-2010/244772#244772
The answer for CheckOut can probably derived from it very easily.
For Read/Write I use very simple POST/DELETE requests. Please comment, if you still want a more explicit answer here.

Answer (score 1):

All the listed operations are supported. I would recommend you to check out the following informations on the web and MSDN:

[Working with files and folders with REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553(v=office.15).aspx)

[Working with list items with REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552(v=office.15).aspx)

[Upload files by using REST and Jquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: I need REST for SP 2010

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a REST API for Sharepoint 2010 out of the box. If possible, the SPServices jQuery-based library at https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices can help you access SharePoint's SOAP interface.